# how to find the limit of f(x) when x tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[1,\infty]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(1)=1$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+f(x)^2}$. Then how can I find the limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Clearly $f'(x)>0$ and so $f$ is strictly increasing. Again $f(1)=1$. So $f(x)\geq 1$ for $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Now I don't get any way to calculate the limit of $f(x)$. Please help.

Comment: Suppose the limit is $L<\infty$. Then $f'(x) \ge \frac1{1+L^2}$ for all $x$. Now try applying the mean value theorem at points $x$, $y$ which are large enough that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are both close to $L$, but $x$ and $y$ are still very far apart.

Comment: Parts of your post ask for the limit of $f$ while other parts ask for the limit of $f'$. Which is it? (An edit by D_S has changed the title as well.)

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I have edited it.

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing either it tends to a limit $L\geq 1$ or to $\infty $. If $f(x) \to L$ then $f'(x) \to 1/(1+L^2)>0$. Now can you get a contradiction by applying L'Hospital's Rule to $f(x) /x$? You may also use mean value theorem to get contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You have for all $x \ge 1$

$$\left(1 + f^2(x)\right) f^\prime(x) = 1$$ Hence

$$\int_1^x \left(1 + f^2(t)\right) f^\prime(t) \ dt= (x-1)$$ and

$$\int_{f(1)}^{f(x)} \left(1 + t^2\right) \ dt= (x-1)$$

As $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (x-1)= \infty$, previous equality implies $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)= \infty$ as $v \mapsto \int_1^v \left(1 + t^2\right) \ dt$ is positive and strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$.